# Spring Boot docker microservices restTemplate exception

Tags: docker, spring-boot, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a `rest` request through `restTemplate` between `Spring Boot` microservices in `docker`, but I get an error.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
  api:
    image: api-service
    container_name: api-service
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - product
    ports:
      - 8081:8080
    links:
      - product:product
    environment:
      - SERVICE_PORT_PRODUCT=8083

  product:
    image: product-service
    container_name: product-service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8083:8080
```

`Exception` log:

```
ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://product:8083/api/products/": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

looks correct:

**POST request for "http://product:8083/api/products/"**

why does not it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As documented in the official docs for [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

> Networked service-to-service communication use the CONTAINER_PORT

Thus when you want to do a request from one container to the other, you need use the container port and not the host port.

The request should be to: http://product:8080/api/products/ from the api container to the product container.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me going insane :D